# Eclipse plugin-Control closing of editor

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What I am cunrrently doing is while closing the editor in `doSave` method I check for a condition If it is satisfied I allow `super.doSave()` be called else I display a dialog box displaying the error message.

Now I want to instead ask user again if he want to save it again and if he says yes he could save  the wrong file or say no to edit it but in either case editor should not close.
However currently after the error it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your editor part implements `ISaveablePart2` Eclipse will call the method:

```java
public int promptToSaveOnClose();
```

to prompt for saving when closing. You can respond with `ISaveablePart2.CANCEL` to cancel the close, `ISaveablePart2.YES` to continue the save (by calling `doSave`), `ISaveablePart2.NO` to skip the save, or `ISaveablePart2.DEFAULT` to use the normal behavior.

Comment: According to my case I wantedthe validation to be in the doSave method so I thought it would be better if I cancel the progressmonitor thereby preventing closing of editor.